# Confused about "replace_more" (PRAW)?

Tags: python, praw

Regarding the documentation on this page: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/comments.html

I am confused about the difference between removing vs replacing MoreComments objects. Specifically, in regard to replacing, what is the MoreComments object replaced with when setting the "limit" to None?

UPDATE: Looks like each MoreComments object is being replaced by further comments. Are these comments further top level comments? And, if so, is it necessary to replace all MoreComments objects with its children comments in order to gather all top level comments for a submission thread?